# AVPlayerViewController stuck on first frame of local video

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

In one of my ViewControllers, I have an `AVPlayerViewController`. In my `viewDidLoad` I have

```
self.videoPlayerController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
```

Then, I play a video using the following method

```
- (void)playVideo:(NSURL*)videoURL {
    [self presentViewController:self.videoPlayerController animated:YES completion:^(){
        AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:videoURL];
        [self.videoPlayerController setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];
        [self.videoPlayerController setPlayer:player];
        [self.videoPlayerController.player play];
    }];
}
```

When playing a video for the first time, the `AVPlayerViewController` appears, but the video is stuck on the first frame, and will not play. No audio plays either.

In iOS 10.0, the seekbar in the on screen controls show that the video is playing (it will progress to the end). In iOS 10.2 however, the seekbar is stuck at 0:00 as well.

I am experiencing this problem on iPads with iOS versions 10.0 and 10.2, however, it works in the XCode simulator (both 10.0 and 10.2).

My problem is similar in nature to [this.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50322)

Also, the video plays correctly if you close the ViewController containing the `AVPlayerViewController`, reopen it, and attempt to play the video again.

Comment: Did you solve it? I got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is in your video file. Try to download another video [mp4 video sample](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4). Add it to your project and try.

Comment: You may be on to something, all of my videos are MP4s, and h.264 encoded, and the one's that have AAC as well do not play. Those without the audio codec do play correctly.